# Aws lambda function with jasmine tests?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, jasmine

i'm working with aws codepipeline and aws lambda functions and i want to integrate some jasmine tests . My question is : Can i use aws lambda function to run my jasmine tests ?

Comment: Is the actual project you want to build and deploy a lambda function or is it some type of other "stack" that you just want to run jasmine tests against?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. But it is not recommended.

Remember that with AWS Lambda you are billed by the duration of your invocations. While most Lambda invocations take only milliseconds of execution time, most automated tests take several seconds to even minutes of execution time.

That would simply make your tests a lot more expensive than your actual application.

Comment: thank you for your answer , i'm trying to find the best way to run my jasmine tests Can you please advise me  and tell me what is the best aws service to run the tests (  between elastic beanstalk and codebuild ) ?

Comment: @bacemmehri AWS Codestar, CodePipeline and CodeBuild would be your best bet.

Comment: thank you so much , u're the best . Just one more question if possible can you give me an exemple of how can i run my jasmine tests with lambda function ( just for information )